# How to use in javascript some data coming from lua files?

Tags: javascript, lua

I have some lua files that I need to read in JS.
I would like to be able to import the variables (mostly tables) and go through them easily in JS, to add things in the DOM.

Exemple of LUA file:

```
print("lua display text")

Civs = { 
    CIVILIZATION_EGYPT = { -- lua comment 1
        Playable = true,
        SpawnYear = -3000,
        StartX = 75,
        StartY = 32,
        Table = { },
        Text = "abc",
        TableTable = { {"a"}, {"b"}, {"c"}, {"d"}, {}, {}, {}},
    };
    CIVILIZATION_INDIA = { 
        Playable = true,
        SpawnYear = -3000,
        StartX = 98,
        StartY = 42,
        Table = { },
        Text = "abc",
        TableTable = { {"a"}, {"b"}, {"c"}, {"d"}, {}, {}, {}},
    };
    CIVILIZATION_BABYLON = {
        Playable = true,
        SpawnYear = -3000,
        StartX = 84,
        StartY = 41,
        Table = { },
        Text = "abc",
        TableTable = { {"a"}, {"b"}, {"c"}, {"d"}, {}, {}, {}},
     }
}
-- lua comment 2
```

Comment: convert them to json?

Comment: how would you do this? in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple json libraries available for Lua. You can use them to serialize Lua tables into json strings.

See http://lua-users.org/wiki/JsonModules

Encoding example for dkjson:

```
local json = require ("dkjson")

local str = json.encode (Civs, { indent = true })

print (str)
```

Comment: Thanks!
In the end, because the lua data files are not often modified, I chose to create a python script that reads them and translate the data I need into a .js file. This way the js will execute faster and I avoid Cross Origin Request Security (CORS) error for locally accessing a .lua file via js.